# Bash frost forecast for gardeners?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting, cron

I would like an automatic frost alert for gardeners as a bash script. Here's what I had in mind:

On https://askubuntu.com/questions/390329/weather-from-terminal there are loads of ideas how to get weather forecast info into the terminal. (This one might be good : "For even shorter weather output http://weather.tuxnet24.de provides weather data from Yahoo! in text and xml format." ?)

Now the challenging part -which I don't know how to do- is to write a script that:

1. examines the gardener's local weather forecast data on a daily basis,
2. extracts temperature data (for the next 5 days let's say) from weather forecast,
3. analyzes them to detect temperatures of 0 degrees or below and
4. automatically alerts the user in advance when frost is on the way.

Which tools could I use? Does anyone feel like trying/helping/cooperating?

Comment: Why does it have to be a bash script? Pain awaits you, great pain. If you want to do it just for fun, and you're a masochist, fine. Otherwise, do consider a more modern and sane scripting / programming environment such as Python.

Comment: Don't listen to language snobs.  python might be marginally better suited but this can easily be done in bash and probably wouldn't even take more than 100 lines of code.

Comment: Unfortunately and obligatory: this isn't a script writing service.  You are unlikely to find people willing to write you a fully functioning program from scratch on here.  Show us what you have tried and where it fails and people will certainly help you make it right.  Also what method of alerting are you looking for?

Comment: @jesse_b It can be done "easily" **if** you're already a Bash hero, which OP said he isn't. There are defensible reasons for wanting to become one, but this task isn't one of them. It's simply the wrong tool for the job, and it's the wrong language to learn for general-purpose programming in today's world. I'm not a language snob and Python is of course not the only totally reasonable option, just the first that came to my mind to recommend to a beginner.

Comment: @TypeIA: I partially disagree.  If you can do something on the command line then you can do it in "bash".  Most bash scripts are barely bash but instead simply the unix pipeline philosophy in a file.  If someone wants to learn their first language I would suggest python over shell because the most difficult language to learn is your second, however if someone isn't interested in learning a language but instead just wants to accomplish a simple task (which believe it or not this is) shell is definitely a more approachable solution.

Comment: thanks a lot both of you for reacting. I have done some bash experimenting and even started reading into python basics in the past, but experience has taught me that it's generally a good idea to first consult people who know how to do things ; so here's as far as i got so far: if i write "curl wttr.in/paris" in a terminal, values show up, but if i type "curl wttr.in/paris > weather" and then "nano weather", those values are replaced by a reference to -in this case- paris... which means I can't just extract them for use in a script... any solutions?

Comment: start with `curl -s wttr.in/paris?format=j1` and then get proficient with `jq`.

Comment: @jesse_b thanks for the advice! jq manages to output `'.current_condition'` data nicely, but when I try a next level e.g. `jq '.current_condition.humidity' meteoparis.json`, I get `'jq: error (at meteoparis.json:1238): Cannot index array with string "humidity"` .. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ferret:`jq '.current_condition[].humidity'` since `current_condition` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short bash script I have written that will accomplish generally what you need.  This will only check the current day and 2 days into the future as that is what wttr.in returns by default but I'm sure you can find some option to expand it if needed.  You may have to play with the mail sending part of the script depending on the system you are running and what options you have available but that would certainly warrant another question if you get stuck on it.  You could add this script to your crontab as a daily job and receive emails about upcoming freezing temperatures.

If the farmers are using something like pagerduty (hah) you could change the mail part out for a webhook to send them alerts through it or just email the pagerduty address.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

json=$(curl -Ss "wttr.in/paris?format=j1")

for ((i=0;i<=2;i++)); do
    date=$(jq -r --arg index "$i" '.weather[$index | tonumber] | .date' <<<"$json")
    temp=$(jq -r --arg index "$i" '.weather[$index | tonumber] | .mintempC' <<<"$json")
    if [[ $temp -le 0 ]]; then
        mail -s "There will be frost on $date ($temp degrees)" youremail@example.com
    fi
done
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I figured out geolocalization coordinates can be used like so: `wttr.in/44.65687,6.657543`, which makes this adapted to any place on the planet. Also changed the mail part into a simple `echo` for now, trying to figure out how to make thunderbird compose & send email from terminal.. guess that would be worth another question if the answer isn't out there already ;) I actually first tried with `json=$(curl -s 'https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?lat=44.98&lon=6.75'|json_pp")` but my jq proficiency isn't yet where it should to adapt the rest.. Thanks!!!